# Triple monitor on Nvidia and Intel

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I want to use 3 monitors, one on built-in Intel iGPU card and 2 on PCI-E Nvidia card on desktop. Is this setup possible?

Searching gives Bumblebee for Optimus technology on notebooks, I tried and it gives only one Intel card working.

Using Nvidia driver gives Nvidia card working for X desktop and Intel card working for TTY's. Also there is wrong resolution on Nvidia monitors.

Using free driver that comes with Ubuntu gives 3 monitors working but display quality is poor, mouse cursor is flashing.

`nouveau` is not in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
lspci -k | grep -E "VGA|Display"
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3] (rev a2)
```

Switching primary display in BIOS toggles cards, both do not work in any case.

Similar unanswered questions:

- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/802206/igpu-and-nvidia-gpu-for-3-monitors/
- [Three screens with Nvidia video card and Intel HD graphics?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473325/three-screens-with-nvidia-video-card-and-intel-hd-graphics?rq=1)
- [Can X.org Load Two Different Drivers? (Triple-Head Setup with Intel and NVidia Card)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280651/can-x-org-load-two-different-drivers-triple-head-setup-with-intel-and-nvidia-c?rq=1)

Comment: Bumblee Bee project could not handle integrated Intel and seperated Nvidia graphic card thing on that day. I think this is a so far away thing to solve.